# A bijective function

Tags: combinatorics

Consider $D_2 = \{(0,0), (0,1), (0,2), (1,0), (1,1), (2,0) \}$ and the bijective function $f_2:D_2 \rightarrow D_2$ defined by
\begin{equation*}
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
(0,0) \rightarrow (2,0) \\
(0,1) \rightarrow (1,1) \\
(0,2) \rightarrow (1,0) \\
(1,0) \rightarrow (0,2) \\
(1,1) \rightarrow (0,1) \\
(2,0) \rightarrow (0,0)
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation*}
Consider $D_3 = \{(0,0,0), (0,0,1), (0,0,2), (0,0,3), (0,1,0), (0,1,1), (0,1,2), (0,2,0), (0,2,1), (0,3,0), (1,0,0), (1,0,1), (1,0,2), (1,1,0), (1,1,1), (1,2,0), (2,0,0), (2,0,1), (2,1,0), (3,0,0) \}$ and the bijective function $f_3:D_3 \rightarrow D_3$ defined by
\begin{equation*}
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
(0,0,0) \rightarrow (3,0,0) \\
(0,0,1) \rightarrow (2,1,0) \\
(0,0,2) \rightarrow (2,0,1) \\
(0,0,3) \rightarrow (2,0,0) \\
(0,1,0) \rightarrow (1,2,0) \\
(0,1,1) \rightarrow (1,1,1) \\
(0,1,2) \rightarrow (1,1,0) \\
(0,2,0) \rightarrow (1,0,2) \\
(0,2,1) \rightarrow (1,0,1) \\
(0,3,0) \rightarrow (1,0,0) \\
(1,0,0) \rightarrow (0,3,0) \\
(1,0,1) \rightarrow (0,2,1) \\
(1,0,2) \rightarrow (0,2,0) \\
(1,1,0) \rightarrow (0,1,2) \\
(1,1,1) \rightarrow (0,1,1) \\
(1,2,0) \rightarrow (0,1,0) \\
(2,0,0) \rightarrow (0,0,3) \\
(2,0,1) \rightarrow (0,0,2) \\
(2,1,0) \rightarrow (0,0,1) \\
(3,0,0) \rightarrow (0,0,0) \\
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation*}
and all the next bijective functions defined in this manner. Question: what is the explicit expression of the components of $f_n:D_n \rightarrow D_n$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Do you know how to describe $D_n$ in general or is that part of the problem?

Comment: $D_2=\{(k,l): k+l\leq 2\}$

Comment: the componenets of the $i$-th element of the set $D_n$ are the digits of the  number i in its representation in base (n+1) with some 0s in front(if needed) to make n digits in total, e.g. the 8th element of $D_3$ will be (0,2,0), since $8 = 20_{(4)}$ and we have 1 zero in front of this representation in order to have 3 digits in total